# Training with step decay not retaining the last epoch when re-running model.fit. Learning rate wrong

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a model by using the `tf.keras` framework with step decay learning rate. However, each time I call the `fit` method, the learning rate is restarted and does not continues from its last state.

The following code is a minimal example that demonstrate the problem.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Create dummy data
train_x = np.random.randint(10,size=40).reshape(-1,1)
train_y = np.random.randint(2,size=40).reshape(-1,1)
train_set = (train_x,train_y)
val_x = np.random.randint(10,size=20).reshape(-1,1)
val_y = np.random.randint(2,size=20).reshape(-1,1)
val_set = (val_x,val_y)

# Creates the model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='relu',use_bias=False,input_dim=(1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100,activation='relu',use_bias=False))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='relu',use_bias=False))

# Indicates training parameters
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',         
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics=['accuracy'])

# Set Learning Rate Decay
import math
def step_decay(epoch):
    print('---',epoch)
    init_lr = 0.001
    drop = 0.9
    epochs_drop = 1.0
    lr = init_lr*math.pow(drop,math.floor((1+epoch)/epochs_drop))
    return(lr)

lr_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)

# Prints 0.001
print('Learning Rate: ',tf.keras.backend.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
model.fit(x=train_set[0],y=train_set[1],epochs=2,steps_per_epoch=40,
            validation_data=val_set,validation_steps=20,
            callbacks=[lr_callback])

# Prints 0.00081
print('Learning Rate: ',tf.keras.backend.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
model.fit(x=train_set[0],y=train_set[1],epochs=2,steps_per_epoch=40,
            validation_data=val_set,validation_steps=20,
            callbacks=[lr_callback])

# Prints 0.00081
print('Learning Rate: ',tf.keras.backend.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
```

As you can see, my `step_decay` function depends on the epoch it is provided. I would expect the model to save the last epoch it ran and provide that epoch to the Learning Rate Scheduler, but this is not the case. Each time I run `fit` the epoch starts again from zero.

So I would like to ask if anyone knows how to retain the state of the last epoch so the learning rate can be calculated correctly depending on the current epoch it is training on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is parameter in `initial_epoch` in `fit` function, you can use that. For example:

```
print('Learning Rate: ',tf.keras.backend.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
model.fit(X_train,Y_train1, batch_size=16,
         validation_split=.5, verbose=1, epochs=2,
            callbacks=[lr_callback])

print('Learning Rate: ',tf.keras.backend.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
```

You have train your model for two epochs, now on again restart, you start from here, and run for one more epoch, that would be epochs=3.

```
print('Learning Rate: ',tf.keras.backend.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
model.fit(X_train,Y_train1, batch_size=16,initial_epoch=2,
         validation_split=.5, verbose=1, epochs=3,
            callbacks=[lr_callback])

print('Learning Rate: ',tf.keras.backend.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
```